# How do I reinstall PHP after fail upgrade?

Tags: php, php-5.5, php-5.6

On Ubuntu 14.04, I've used PHP 5.5 from ondrej PPA.
I wanted to upgrade to PHP 5.6.

Added new PPA, `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.
There was failures with `php5-json`.
I've purged all PHP, all PHP PPA repos, removed `/etc/php5 /usr/lib/php5 /var/lib/php5`.

Added PHP 5.6 PPA - getting next:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install php5-json
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  php5-common
Suggested packages:
  php5-user-cache
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-common php5-json
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/728 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,331 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Selecting previously unselected package php5-common.
(Reading database ... 182833 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php5-common_5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php5-common (5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php5-json.
Preparing to unpack .../php5-json_1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php5-json (1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up php5-common (5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini with new version
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-json:
 php5-json depends on phpapi-20121212; however:
  Package phpapi-20121212 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package php5-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-json
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you try purging specifically the php5-json package and give us the output?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale thanks you for help, I've found solution, posted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```